# Data Pump Job error caused by time zone

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm running a impdp command for a dmp file, but when i read the log file, it show a error like this:

```
ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -30094
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in DISPATCH
ORA-30094: failed to find the time zone data file for version 4 in $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo
```

I've checked version using  `SELECT * from v$timezone_file;`, and the result displayed is 14.

And i'm running the impdp on server with the following properties:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

I've read about upgrading versions, but I don't quite understand the concept of it, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Express did not ship with a full set of timezones definitions for some reason. See here: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2011/11/ora-30094-failed-to-find-time-zone-data.html?m=1

The recommended "fix" would be to do a software-only of the full Oracle version and copy the files from there. Unfortunately, Oracle 11 is no longer available, so my recommendation would be to - if possible - use Oracle XE 18 instead of 11, and see if you have the same problem. If you do, then get a full software-only install of Oracle 18 or 19 and copy the timezone files from there.